# Install android-ndk toolchain for arm-64

Tags: android, android-ndk, termux

I have to install toolchain for arm-64 instead of amd-64!

I don't know how to install toolchain for arm-64!

I tried with android-ndk-r23b.

This is the command for installation of toolchain

```
$NDK/build/tools/make_standalone_toolchain.py \                 --arch arm64 \                                                    --api 29 \                                                        --install-dir=toolchain
```

I have to install toolchain for arm-64, to cross-compile SFML C++ from Android Termux.

Android version 10.

Comment: How did you install the toolchain?

Comment: @zomega I shared that right now in edited post, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for android-ndk setup for aarch64(arm-64) most probably android/chromium-pc .. there's not quite any yet. but soon they'll be popular.

You can check out [ndk release by lzhiyong](https://github.com/lzhiyong/termux-ndk/releases)

He also has a headstart guide to build toolchain from source [here](https://github.com/Lzhiyong/termux-ndk/tree/master/docs)

and how to build apps from ndk in android : [here build termux from termux](https://github.com/Lzhiyong/termux-ndk/tree/master/build-app)

Answer (score 0):

You've missunderstood the architecture of the toolchain. If you have the amd64 toolchain you can cross compile for arm64, arm32 and x86 (maybe others).

So what you need is the amd64 toolchain which seems to be the architecture of your development PC.

Also I don't recommand to build the toolchain yourself. Instead you can download it prebuilt from Google.

If you're using Android Studio you can download the NDK which includes the toolchain using the GUI SDK manager.

The SDK manager can also be run from the [command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager) (only do this if you're not using Android Studio).

The NDK can also be downloaded as ZIP file. This is the best option if you need nothing more than the NDK.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I tried one, two, three times different toolchain, followed ChatGPT with it's guide 4 times, yet I can't succed. I'm trying to cross compile C++ SFML on Termux Android. Can you please help?

Comment: @NothingButAir You want to compile SFML under Termux? Why? Compile it on a normal PC instead. Under Ubuntu for example.

Comment: Because I need to have fully independent compiler for graphical output with C++ on my phone.

Comment: @NothingButAir You said in your original question you want to compile SFML on a x86_64 PC. Now you say you want to compile it on a phone under Termux. It's hard to give you an advice if you change your aims.

Comment: I don't even know what I'm talking about, sorry.

Comment: I'm really sorry about that, I thought it will be easier.

Comment: @NothingButAir If you want to run SFML on your phone you have to cross-compile it on your PC. You don't have to compile anything on your phone. Here are tutorials for both Windows and Linux: https://github.com/acsbendi/Build-SFML-For-Android-On-Windows https://github.com/acsbendi/Build-SFML-For-Android-On-Linux